# ZXing in Universal App bitmap

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, qr-code, zxing

I am having an older code for ZXing which works fine with `Bitmaps` but in my Win10 Universal App I am working with `BitmapImage`. Can you give me an Idea if ZXing also accept other `BitmapImage`, or how do I get to the point that it works?

When I use `using System.Drawing;` in the Class of my Win10 App I am getting an Error while compiling:

> System.MarshalByRefObject not found

This is my old working code:

```
private string DecodeQRCodeFromBitmap(System.Drawing.Bitmap Picture)
{

    dynamic luminanceSource = new ZXing.BitmapLuminanceSource(Picture);
    dynamic binarizer = new ZXing.Common.HybridBinarizer(luminanceSource);


    ZXing.BinaryBitmap bb = new ZXing.BinaryBitmap(binarizer);
    ZXing.Result br = readCode2.decode(bb);
    if (br != null) {
        Interaction.MsgBox(br.ToString);
        return Convert.ToString(br.Text);
    } else {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

New not working code:

```
    private string DecodeQRCodeFromBitmap(BitmapImage image)
    {
        dynamic luminanceSource = new ZXing.BitmapLuminanceSource(image);
        dynamic binarizer = new      ZXing.Common.HybridBinarizer(luminanceSource);

        ZXing.BinaryBitmap bb = new ZXing.BinaryBitmap(binarizer);
        ZXing.Result br = readCode.decode(bb);
        if (br != null)
        {
            return Convert.ToString(br.Text);
        }
        else {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a small sample for decoding barcodes in a windows universal app. It is in vb.net but you can convert it to c# ... or ask me at work ...

```
Imports Windows.Media.Capture
Imports Windows.Storage.Streams
Imports Windows.Media.MediaProperties

Public NotInheritable Class MainPage
    Inherits Page

    Private capture As MediaCapture

    Private Async Function TakePhoto() As Task
        Try
            capture = New MediaCapture
            Await capture.InitializeAsync
            captureElementPreview.Source = capture
            Await capture.StartPreviewAsync
            Dim res As VideoEncodingProperties = capture.VideoDeviceController.GetMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview)
            Dim iep As ImageEncodingProperties = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateBmp
            iep.Height = res.Height
            iep.Width = res.Width
            Dim barcodereader As New ZXing.BarcodeReader With {.AutoRotate = True}
            Dim wb As New WriteableBitmap(res.Width, res.Height)
            Dim result As ZXing.Result = Nothing
            While result Is Nothing
                Using stream = New InMemoryRandomAccessStream()
                    Await capture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(iep, stream)
                    stream.Seek(0)
                    Await wb.SetSourceAsync(stream)
                    result = barcodereader.Decode(wb)
                End Using
            End While
            Scanresult.Text = result.Text
            Await capture.StopPreviewAsync
            Debug.WriteLine(Scanresult.Text)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception when taking a photo: {0}", ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End Function

    Private Async Sub buttonCapture_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Await TakePhoto()
    End Sub

End Class
```

You need to import the zxing.winrt.dll from the subfolder \winrt of the zxing library. I take this code from another post in stackoverflow. Many things can be better but it works for the first steps ...

Greetings Frank